# Can a phase requiring two colored sets be completed with the same color?

Tags: phase-10

In Phase 10 can a phase requiring collecting x of one color and y of one color be completed using x+y of the same color?

E.G.
Can **Candy Castle / Mountain Vista** Phase 7 (*4 of one color + 6 of one color*) or Phase 8 (*5 of one color + 5 of one color*) be completed with 10 of the same color?

or

Can **Cocoa Canyon** Phase 3 (*4 cards of one color + 5 cards of one color*) be completed with 9 card of the same color?

Comment: which version of phase 10 has a set of 5 of a color and set of 4 of a color? Some quick searching is not showing this combo

Comment: Canyon phase I think

Comment: Looks like it's phase 3 of the "Cocoa Canyon" version, according to Wikipedia.

Comment: I would assume it would follow that the  same rules as if you can use 1 number for both set in any of the phases.  If you would allow some one with 6 of one number to go down on the first phase (2 set of 3) in the regular game then I would allow this.

Comment: As an aside, the odds of this situation coming up in an actual game are so slim that it almost makes this a moot point.  Ignoring wilds and skips, the probability of getting dealt a hand you can make phase with on the first turn using two different colors for candy castle phase 7 is about $0.00076$ while making phase on the first turn with only one color is about $0.00000017$, more than a thousand times less likely.  In terms of actual play, the obviously superior strategy is to collect two colors unless you happened to have been dealt nine of a single color.

Answer (score 1):

Since the wording of the phases as started say "of one color" for both colors instead of the second part of the phase saying "of another color" or "of one other color" the answer is yes, it is allowed.

Comment: Am wondering if something like phases could also be added to a varient of canasta

Comment: Phase 10 ideas in the game magic the gathering could be interesting too